# Test performance between Tomcat BIO and NIO connectors

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, nio

I would like to observe the performance improvement of using NIO connector vs BIO connector on Apache Tomcat. The differences between BIO and NIO is, (quoting from [DZONE](https://dzone.com/articles/tomcats-default-connectors)),

> The BIO connector (blocking I/O) is blocking – it uses a thread pool
> where each thread receives a request, handles it, responds, and is
> returned to the pool.
>
> The NIO connector (non-blocking I/O) uses the java NIO library and
> multiplexes between requests. It has two thread pools – one holds the
> the poller threads, which handle all incoming requests and push these
> requests to be handled by worker threads, held in another pool.

I learnt from documentation that Apache Tomcat 7 defaults to BIO but is configurable to be used with NIO conenctor. Starting from Apache Tomcat 8.5 BIO connector is [removed completely](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#BIO_connector_removed) and NIO is the default considering that NIO is non blocking.

Inorder to visualize/compare the performance of BIO and NIO connector I have setup a test application that has REST API that serves response after waiting a random period of time between 1-30 seconds, and this test application is deployed on Apache Tomcat 7. I have set maxThread=300, minSpareThreads=10 under 'Executor' section of server.xml file.

I varied the tests between setting connector protocol between BIO and NIO (in settings.xml) and ran the test with a load of 5000 requests dispersed over 60 second window via Jmeter and observed the thread and cpu consumption on Jconsole, I varied the test duration with few other parameters and I expected to see NIO to consume less number of threads compared to BIO connector but I end up getting similiar results for either of the cases (NIO or BIO).

I would like to figure out the specific testcase scenario that I need to follow such that I get to observe that NIO performs better than BIO connector on Apache Tomcat 7. Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Tomcat 7 has [long reached its end of life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-70-eol.html), 2.5 years ago at the time of you asking this question. Why bother about its performance?

Comment: Unfortunately we have hundreds of application still running on Tomcat 7 which came shipped with RHEL. We cannot migrate all of these applications right away due to the challenge that RedHat has stopped shipping packaged Tomcat as part of their RHEL support so when we do migrate we need to migrate to JBOSS that now come shipped with newer RHEL (along with RedHat support). At this time we are stuck with Tomcat 7 for sometime.

Comment: I don't understand... you need to go with something supported, thus you're stuck with something outdated and unsupported? I'd still not invest a lot into outdated infrastructure and rather invest the time more wisely.

Comment: I agree, the best approach is to go with something supported which requires purchasing new RHEL OS, migrate hundreds of applications that we have to newer OS and hopefully newer Java version. But this is a mammoth effort and  is going to take atleast an year or two. In the interest of time I would like to improve what we have right now and In order to improve I would like to find out how to measure the advantage of NIO connector vs BIO connector.

Comment: Why don't you test the tomcat 7 vs tomcat 8 performance? It will give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to give a correct answer the way the question is currently written. Probably doing stress tests NIO will behave better before breaking than BIO. But as always tests need to be done to confirm.

My recommendation would be to not try to test NIO vs BIO in an abstract use case. Test your real life applications with both in real life conditions. That will give a better idea of which configuration is better for your each type of your existing applications.

Comment: Thank you @aled  for the response. My question is around testing process, what kind of stress test can I do to observe NIO outperform BIO. In order to apply this change in the production I need to say "Hey this NIO connector is certainly better than BIO" and in order for me to say that I need to observe it. Do you recommend any specific test that I can perform on my application on a test environment to observe the difference between NIO and BIO?

Comment: [Stress tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_(computing)) are a type of testing. Increase the load of the system until it breaks, analyze performance along the curve. You need to analyze the results of tests, make changes, test again, to understand if it really works better for you. We can not know if there is a specific scenario that proves what you want but under heavy load is the best bet.